# add html to page if iframe has content

Tags: jquery, iframe

Have a form here like this :

```
    <form id="form_710370" class="appnitro"  method="post" target="my-iframe" action="mypage.php">
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and have an iframe

```
<iframe id="my_frame" name="my-iframe" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

so I am loading the output of my php file to this iframe. Now I need to display a form after the iframe has contents. I just tried with this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            var adFrame = $("#my_frame");
            var adContainer = $("#test_form_wrapper");
            if(adFrame.contents().find("body").html()=="") {
                adContainer.css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                alert("HERE");
                adContainer.css('display', 'block');
            }
        });
```

and the div I need to show is  :

```
 <div id="test_form_wrapper"><span>This is a test div</span>    </div>
```

the script is hiding the div on the page load as the iframe don't have any content. But this is not showing the div after iframe has contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
var adFrame = $("#my_frame");
var adContainer = $("#test_form_wrapper"); 
 $( document ).ready(function() {

                if(adFrame.contents().find("body").html()=="") {
                    adContainer.css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    alert("HERE");
                    adContainer.css('display', 'block');
                }
            });
function recheck()
{
if(adFrame.contents().find("body").html()=="")
{
                    adContainer.css('display', 'none');
                } else {
                    alert("HERE");
                    adContainer.css('display', 'block');
                }
}
```

should call function recheck() again after loading your php into